# undefined local variable or method for method located in lib directory file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some code i've inherited and am in the process of upgrading it to Rails 3.1. I'm suuuuper close to done but I got a bug.

In Rails Console I run `User.first` and I get this error

```
undefined local variable or method `acts_as_userstamp' for #<Class:0x000000046bef50>
```

Now `acts_as_userstamp` is a method located on line two inside my User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #TODO /lib is not loading??? or is it??? why this method not work in browser?
  acts_as_userstamp
```

And is defined in a file called `app/lib/model_modifications.rb`.

Now I recently discovered that my `app/lib` folder was not being autoloaded in my `application.rb` file and I think that's been fixed...or has it? Is this file correct? Or no?

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# evil outdated soap middleware, TODO: kill it with fire
# Does this have to be loaded BEFORE the first line???
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', "vendor", "soap4r"))
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', "vendor", "plugins", "soap4r-middleware", "lib"))

# evil outdated soap middleware, TODO: kill it with fire
require 'soap4r-middleware'
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'app', 'lib', 'soap.rb')

if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require *Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module MyappDev
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # startup the lib directory goodies <-- IS THIS CORRECT???
    # config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib"
    # config.autoload_paths += %W( lib/ )
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
    config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]

    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]
    config.middleware.use MyAPIMiddleware
  end
end
```

I'm trying to debug this file as I post this now. Here is a peak at it's internal structure...(i've just included the overall structure for the sake of brevity)

app/lib/model_modificatons.rb

```
class Bignum
...
end
class Fixnum
...
end
class ProcessorDaemon
...
end

module ActiveRecord
  module UserMonitor
  ...
  end
  module MyLogger
  ...
  end
end

class Object
...
end
class Struct
... 
end
class String
...
end
class Fixnum
...
end
class OpenStruct
...
end

class ActiveRecord::Base
   def self.visible_columns
   ...
   end
   
   ...

   def self.acts_as_userstamp
      logger.info "HI fonso - acts_as_userstamp is called"
      include ActiveRecord::UserMonitor
   end
   
   ...
   
   protected

   def self.range_math(*ranges)
     ...
   end
end

class Array
...
end

class DB
...
end
```

If you can spot a problem with the overall structure or anywhere else please let me know.

So why is this method not found? I'm trying to debug it as I'm posting this and I'm getting nothing.

I suspect the file `app/lib/model_modifications.rb` is not being loading. That nothing in the /lib directory is being loaded..but how do I confirm this?

Thank you for reading this far, I hope I've not rambled on too much.

Comment: You can always put a manual `require` in `application.rb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`autoload_path` configuration does not load all the given files on the boot but defines folders where rails will be searching for defined constants.

When your application is loaded, most of the constants in your application are not there. Rails have a "clever" way of delaying loading the files by using a `constant_missing` method on Module. Basically, when Ruby encounters a constant in the code and fails to resolve it, it executes said method. THe sntandard implementation of this method is to raise `UndefinedConstant` exception, but rails overrides it to search all of its `autoload_paths` for a file with a name matching the missing constant, require it and then check again if the missing constant is now present.

So, in your code everything works as expected and you need to load this extension file manually. If you want to have some code that executes on the application boot, put your file within `config/initializers` folder.

Aside: Try avoiding monkey patching whenever possible. It might be looking clever, but adding more methods to already overpopulated classes will not make them easier to use.

Comment: This got me over this hump. THANK YOU! (I hear you on the monkey patching unfortunately it's inherited code so I have to deal with the foot that's attached to the ear. )